# How do I simulate a "tick" when testing components with embedded Q.js promises

Tags: q

My app code components often calls upon dependent components that sport asynchronous methods that return Q.js promises. I'd like to write synchronous test of such outer components whenever possible ... mostly because synchronous tests are more readable but also because it can be almost impossible to know when a dependent component is "ready" (as discussed below)

I've designed the dependent components so I can configure them to behave synchronously when under test. But their APIs still return Q.js promises. Even though such a promise will be fully resolved "immediately" (e.g., `return Q(some_data);`), Q guarantees that the promise won't actually resolve until the next tick. This (properly) ensures asynchronous behavior even when the time-to-resolution is effectively zero.

I get it.

But that means I can't write synchronous tests for the app components and I can't control when the ready-to-go promises resolve. I can't test the code at all when the dependent component doesn't expose the promise to the caller ... which it should not do when the method of the dependent component API should be fire-and-forget as is often the case.

It would be great if my test could tell Q that a "tick" had occurred, thus causing it to attempt to resolve queued promises. This idea is inspired by Angular's $q which has this feature baked in (you call `$scope.$apply`) for just this purpose.

I don't see any way to trigger a "tick" in Q today. For sure I do NOT want to monkey-punch `setTimeout`!

Is there a way I don't know about? Would this be a good feature?

Answer (score 0):

It’s an intriguing idea. Q does not provide any way to force flush of the event queue today. There are probably good security and safety reasons to not provide this capability in most cases, and I would certainly encourage writing asynchronous tests for asynchronous systems.  I am interested in hearing feedback on the idea from our panel of active contributors, so I have filed an issue to Q’s next-gen event queue implementation, [ASAP (linked)](https://github.com/kriskowal/asap/issues/26).

Comment: Thanks for considering it. I can see why you might not want that feature in production :).  Of course I would write async tests when I can; they're not THAT hard. But sometimes it's a bear because you don't have access to the promise in SUT. Happens in fire-and-forget calls. Sometimes that call is going to prime a repository w/ initial data to be consumed later. Imagine a promise chain in there. While the data are easily faked; detecting the resolution of the promise chain ... not so easy when you can't grab it. Refactor is like pulling thread on a sweater. Happens more than you think.